# What's the best way to wrap a C callback with a C++11 interface?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback, stdbind

Let's say this is a C function to be wrapped:

```
void foo(int(__stdcall *callback)());
```

The two main pitfalls with C function pointer callbacks are:

- Not being able to store bind expressions
- Not being able to store capturing lambdas

I would like to know the best way to wrap functions like these to do so. The first is particularly useful for a member function callback, and the second for an inline definition that uses surrounding variables, but those are not the only uses.

The other property of these particular function pointers is that they need to use the `__stdcall` calling convention. This, to my knowledge, eliminates lambdas as an option completely, and is a bit of a nuisance otherwise. I'd like to allow at least `__cdecl` as well.

This is the best I am able to come up with without things starting to bend back to relying on support that function pointers don't have. It would typically be in a header. Here is the following example on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d3222865b8c912f23dbe130e9a8bb6d3-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad).

```
#include <functional>

//C function in another header I have no control over
extern "C" void foo(int(__stdcall *callback)()) {
    callback();
}

namespace detail {
    std::function<int()> callback; //pretend extern and defined in cpp

    //compatible with the API, but passes work to above variable
    extern "C" int __stdcall proxyCallback() { //pretend defined in cpp
        //possible additional processing
        return callback();
    }
}

template<typename F> //takes anything
void wrappedFoo(F f) {
    detail::callback = f;
    foo(detail::proxyCallback); //call C function with proxy 
}

int main() {
    wrappedFoo([&]() -> int {
        return 5;
    });   
}
```

There is, however, a major flaw. This is not re-entrant. If the variable is reassigned to before it's used, the old function will never be called (not taking into account multithreading issues).

One thing I have tried that ended up doubling back on itself was storing the `std::function` as a data member and using objects, so each would operate on a different variable, but there was no way to pass the object to the proxy. Taking the object as a parameter would cause the signature to mismatch and binding it would not let the result be stored as a function pointer.

One idea I have, but have not played around with is a vector of `std::function`. However, I think the only real safe time to erase from it would be to clear it when nothing is using it. However, each entry is first added in `wrappedFoo`, then used in `proxyCallback`. I'm wondering if a counter that is incremented in the former and decremented in the latter, then checked for zero before clearing the vector would work, but it sounds like a more convoluted solution than necessary anyway.

Is there any way to wrap a C function with a function pointer callback such that the C++ wrapped version:

- Allows any function object
- Allows more than just the C callback's calling convention (if it's critical that it's the same, the user can pass in something with the right calling convention)
- Is thread-safe/re-entrant

<sub>Note: The obvious solution, stated as part of Mikael Persson's answer, is to make use of the `void *` parameter that should exist. However, this is sadly not a be-all, end-all option, mostly due to incompetence. What possibilities exist for those functions that do not have this option is where this can get interesting, and is the primary route to a very useful answer.</sub>

Comment: "*This is not re-entrant. If the variable is reassigned to before it's used, the old function will never be called (not taking into account multithreading issues).*" If that's happening, then aren't you in the process of setting the same callback from *two different threads*? Unless the callback system you're registering with can handle that, it doesn't matter whether your wrapper system can. Broken is broken, whether it's in your code or theirs.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Well, it definitely can. I was hesitant to mention that this question spawned from the Windows API `CreateWindow`, which should be fine being called from two threads at once AFAIK, and also has a (more hidden) `void *` option. The reason for the hesitance was that I meant for the question to be a bit more abstract than that. It's a good point to think about, though.

Comment: @NicolBolas The case described is when the same wrapper function (to which the callback pointer points to) is used for registering multiple callbacks (after multiple calls to the C API function), which cannot work correctly if you have only one global function object (pointing to the actual callback functor / lambda / whatever). This is not related to multi-threading per se, although multi-threading does introduce even more issues.

Comment: @MikaelPersson, I'm appalled at myself, but for some reason, that didn't even cross my mind. That really makes a difference.

Comment: @chris: Your question should only be applicable for callbacks that don't take a user-defined data parameter (ie: `lpParam` that CreateWindow takes). Any callbacks that have such storage will be fine. The only time you need to resort to global shenanigans are for those really annoying callbacks that don't take such parameters.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Yes, and this was meant to be addressed at a more general level than what inspired it, which is (half-)easily solved with that. I might as well edit the question to better reflect that if I can find a wording that doesn't disrupt the existing answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are, unfortunately, out of luck.

There are ways to generate code at runtime, for example you can read on [LLVM trampoline intrinsics](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#trampoline-intrinsics) where you generate a forwarding function that stores additional state, very akin to lambdas but runtime defined.

Unfortunately none of those are standard, and thus you are stranded.

---

The simplest solution to pass state is... to actually pass state. *Ah!*

Well defined C callbacks will take *two* parameters:

- A pointer to the callback function itself
- A `void*`

The latter is unused by the code itself, and simply passed to the callback when it is called. Depending on the interface either the callback is responsible to destroy it, or the supplier, or even a 3rd "destroy" function could be passed.

With such an interface, you can effectively pass state in a thread-safe & re-entrant fashion at the C level, and thus naturally wrap this up in C++ with the same properties.

```
template <typename Result, typename... Args)
Result wrapper(void* state, Args... args) {
    using FuncWrapper = std::function<Result(Args...)>;
    FuncWrapper& w = *reinterpret_cast<FuncWrapper*>(state);
    return w(args...);
}

template <typename Result, typename... Args)
auto make_wrapper(std::function<Result(Args...)>& func)
    -> std::pair<Result (*)(Args...), void*>
{
    void* state = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&func);
    return std::make_pair(&wrapper<Result, Args...>, state);
}
```

---

If the C interface does not provide such facilities, you can hack around a bit, but ultimately you are very limited. As was said, a possible solution is to hold the state externally, using globals, and do your best to avoid contention.

A rough sketch is here:

```
// The FreeList, Store and Release functions are up to you,
// you can use locks, atomics, whatever...
template <size_t N, typename Result, typename... Args>
class Callbacks {
public:
    using FunctionType = Result (*)(Args...);
    using FuncWrapper = std::function<Result(Args...)>;

    static std::pair<FunctionType, size_t> Generate(FuncWrapper&& func) {
        // 1. Using the free-list, find the index in which to store "func"
        size_t const index = Store(std::move(state));

        // 2. Select the appropriate "Call" function and return it
        assert(index < N);
        return std::make_pair(Select<0, N-1>(index), index);
    } // Generate

    static void Release(size_t);

private:
    static size_t FreeList[N];
    static FuncWrapper State[N];

    static size_t Store(FuncWrapper&& func);

    template <size_t I, typename = typename std::enable_if<(I < N)>::type>
    static Result Call(Args...&& args) {
        return State[I](std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } // Call

    template <size_t L, size_t H>
    static FunctionType Select(size_t const index) {
        static size_t const Middle = (L+H)/2;

        if (L == H) { return Call<L>; }

        return index <= Middle ? Select<L, Middle>(index)
                               : Select<Middle + 1, H>(index);
    }

}; // class Callbacks

// Static initialization
template <size_t N, typename Result, typename... Args>
static size_t Callbacks<N, Result, Args...>::FreeList[N] = {};

template <size_t N, typename Result, typename... Args>
static Callbacks<N, Result, Args...>::FuncWrapper Callbacks<N, Result, Args...>::State[N] = {};
```

Comment: Be careful with trampolines because they sometimes require NX-Stacks (and their other trade names, like nested function in GCC). NX-Stacks are sometimes a violation of secure coding/best practices, and code that uses them cannot pass through the security gate. On Windows systems, they are a violation of both secure coding and best practices.

Comment: @jww: That would indeed be a security concern, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

This problem has two challenges: one easy and one nearly impossible.

The first challenge is the static type transformation (mapping) from any callable "thing" to a simple function pointer. This problem is solved with a simple template, no big deal. This solves the calling convention problem (simply wrapping one kind of function with another). This is already solved by the `std::function` template (that's why it exists).

The main challenge is the encapsulation of a run-time state into a plain function pointer whose signature does not allow for a "user-data" `void*` pointer (as any half-decent C API would normally have). This problem is independent of language (C, C++03, C++11) and is nearly impossible to solve.

You have to understand a fundamental fact about any "native" language (and most others too). The code is fixed after compilation, and only the data changes at run-time. So, even a class member function that appears as if it's one function belonging to the object (run-time state), it's not, the code is fixed, only the identity of the object is changed (the `this` pointer).

Another fundamental fact is that all external states that a function can use must either be global or passed as a parameter. If you eliminate the latter, you only have global state to use. And by definition, if the function's operation depends on a global state, it cannot be re-entrant.

So, to be able to create a (sort-of-)re-entrant`*` function that is callable with just a plain function pointer and that encapsulate any general (state-ful) function object (bind'ed calls, lambdas, or whatever), you will need a unique piece of code (not data) for each call. In other words, you need to generate the code at run-time, and deliver a pointer to that code (the callback function-pointer) to the C function. That's where the "nearly impossible" comes from. This is not possible through any standard C++ mechanisms, I'm 100% sure of that, because if this was possible in C++, run-time reflection would also be possible (and it's not).

In theory, this could be easy. All you need is a piece of compiled "template" code (not template in the C++ sense) that you can copy, insert a pointer to your state (or function object) as a kind of hard-coded local variable, and then place that code into some dynamically allocated memory (with some reference counting or whatever to ensure it exists as long as it's needed). But making this happen is clearly very tricky and very much of a "hack". And to be honest, this is quite ahead of my skill level, so I wouldn't even be able to instruct you on how exactly you could go about doing this.

In practice, the realistic option is to not even try to do this. Your solution with the global (extern) variable that you use to pass the state (function object) is going in the right direction in terms of a compromise. You could have something like a pool of functions that each have their own global function object to call, and you keep track of which function is currently used as a callback, and allocate unused ones whenever needed. If you run out of that limited supply of functions, you'll have to throw an exception (or whatever error-reporting you prefer). This scheme would be essentially equivalent to the "in theory" solution above, but with a limited number of concurrent callbacks being used. There are other solutions in a similar vein, but that depends on the nature of the specific application.

I'm sorry that this answer is not giving you a great solution, but sometimes there just aren't any silver bullets.

Another option is to avoid using a C API that was designed by buffoons who never heard of the unavoidable and tremendously useful `void* user_data` parameter.

`*` "sort-of" re-entrant because it still refers to a "global" state, but it is re-entrant in the sense that different callbacks (that need different state) do not interfere with each other, as is your original problem.

Comment: I have to say that pool idea is kind of interesting. I do have some decisions to make about what to give up, but at least most reasonable examples do have `void *` parameters, making that a fairly reasonable answer. For those that don't, not all of them will support being called from two threads at once, so that narrows down the list yet again. From there, it's time for decisions.

Comment: I have two problems with this answer. First, maybe it's just me, but I don't see why runtime code generation would be necessary. If we are hacking, why aren't we hacking such that we inject a pointer to the state itself (which is data only)? The other thing is that runtime code generation itself is not "nearly impossible". If it was, then creating a JIT compiler for a programming language interpreter would also be nearly impossible; however, we have things like LLVM (!), Nitro, JVM, etc.

Comment: +1 just for 'Another option is to avoid using a C API that was designed by buffoons who never heard of the unavoidable and tremendously useful void* user_data parameter.'  I would have gone with 'morons'.  Any lib developer who designs such callback-setup code without such a parameter available in the callback should be fired immediate, (or fired upon, if a squad is available).

Comment: @H2CO3: I concur, although most of the answer is quite well led out, the portion about code generation is just plain wrong... it is not even anything akin to reflection! Mikael Persson: I suggest you read on runtime generated trampolines. They are effectively not standard, specifically because JITting is impossible on a number of platforms where code and data are strictly separate (and JITting requires converting data into code), however they can be used to solve the above problem and some compilers (such as LLVM) support them natively.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for pointing that out. As I said, doing this is "quite ahead of my skill level". And the "nearly impossible" referred to doing this in a standard portable way. This feature of LLVM looks quite interesting, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @MikaelPersson: No problem, we are all here to learn :) I am nothing akin to an expert in this domain either... I never actually wrote a JIT myself or even played with LLVM's one.

Answer (score 2):

As said before, a C function pointer does not contain any state, so a callback function called with no arguments can only access global state. Therefore, such a "stateless" callback function can be used only in one context, where the context is stored in a global variable. Then declare different callbacks for different contexts.

If the number of callbacks required changes dynamically (for example, in a GUI, where each windows opened by the user requires a new callback to handle input to that window), then pre-define a large pool of simple state-less callbacks, that map to a statefull callback. In C, that could be done as follows:

```
struct cbdata { void (*f)(void *); void *arg; } cb[10000];
void cb0000(void) { (*cb[0].f)(cb[0].arg); }
void cb0001(void) { (*cb[1].f)(cb[1].arg); }
...
void cb9999(void) { (*cb[9999].f)(cb[99999].arg); }
void (*cbfs[10000])(void) =
    { cb0000, cb0001, ... cb9999 };
```

Then use some higher level module to keep a list of available callbacks.

With GCC (but not with G++, so the following would need to be in a strictly C, not C++ file), you can create new callback functions even on the fly by using a not-so-well-known GCC feature, nested functions:

```
void makecallback(void *state, void (*cb)(void *), void (*cont)(void *, void (*)()))
{
    void mycallback() { cb(state); }
    cont(state, mycallback);
}
```

In this case, GCC creates the code for the necessary code generation for you. The downside is, that it limits you to the GNU compiler collection, and that the NX bit cannot be used on the stack anymore, as even your code will require new code on the stack.

makecallback() is called from the high-level code to create a new anonymous callback function with encapsulated state. If this new function is called, it will call the statefull callback function cb with arg state. The new anonymous callback function is useable, as long, as makecallback() does not return. Therefore, makecallback() returns control to the calling code by calling the passed in "cont" function. This example assumes, that the actual callback cb() and the normal continue function cont() both use the same state, "state". It is also possible to use two different void pointers to pass different state to both.

The "cont" function may only return (and SHOULD also return to avoid memory leaks), when the callback is no longer required. If your application is multi-threaded, and requires the various callbacks mostly for its various threads, then you should be able to have each thread at startup allocate its required callback(s) via makecallback().

However, if your app is multi-threaded anyways, and if you have (or can establish) a strict callback-to-thread relationship, then you could use thread-local vars to pass the required state. Of course, that will only work, if your lib calls the callback in the right thread.